# Designing crystal report to match a template

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I need to design a crystal report that matches a invoice template. Which means that the page will contain the layout & the crystal report will printout the values in the gives spaces. What is the easiest way to align the labels so that they will print out at the right location on my bill.

***For example***, If I were to get my printout on the invoice sample shown in the below image, how can I align the today's date label right in front of the date field.

[image]

Comment: Incomplete question... but it depends on how your invoice bill is by that you need to decide which lables comes where in the design of the report.

Comment: Please let me know what other info should be included in this question. And I know where the labels should go, but how do I align the labels perfectly so that they print at the right space on the template.

Comment: It is difficult to answer these type of questions where scope of answer is large.... I can provide you a small example.. suppose if for a invoice has a heading then should come either in `Report Header` or `Page header` of the design.. similarly other fields aswell

Comment: @Siva I edited the question & included an example, please be kind enough to recheck the question and share your idea.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to help to the extent I can:

1. Logo, Address and date are printed once then those should be in `report header` so that it will be printed once...

To allign date filed just place the date to the right of the design of the `report header`.

2.if Bill Number and other items are needed only once then place those in `report header`.. If place is not sufficient then increase the size of the header of insert a `section below`.

3.Now group the report with the `item` and place the `Description` etc items in `group header`.

4.Place the values in `Detail` so that those will repeat for the items if there are more values for each item.

5.For `sub total`, `PST`, `GST` take in group footer. If one is not sufficient then insert a section below for each group footer.

6.For `Notes`, `Total`, `Paid`, `Total Due` use report footer as these need to be printed only once.

7.Take one more `report footer` section and write `Thanks for your business`.

Hope I explained what is needed.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my question. I have the template printed before hand from a press. The invoice template exists when I insert the paper to the printer, I just fill in the blank spaces when taking a printout. I just need to know, how I could position the labels exactly on the blank spaces. Sorry if this is not still clear, its very difficult to explain.

Comment: I have certainly misunderstood your question....I apologize as I am not sure on how to do this....

Comment: Oh that's really hard because you need to be precise on where you put the datafield.  This is pure trial and error.  Just like if you have window envelope and wanted to align the address on the paper.   It's alot easier if they just printed the letterhead and let crystal handle the rest.  Anyways, in this situation I would print in a blank sheet and hold it and the template up to the light to see how far off I am.  Then adjust position, font size, and row sizes so it lines up perfectly.  Then print again... this way you save on letterhead.  Sorry it's not more useful.